# Visual Studio Online Fedora Server

Tags: visual-studio, azure

Good day, after the recommendation from the Visual Studio twitter account I come here with a question I want to try to persist to a solution. The problem being, running an instance of Visual Studio Online on Fedora Server 32.

After seeing the new Github Codespace beta release I took time to look into the originating program which was Visual Studio Online. After signing up for my Azure account I looked into possible solutions to host it on the CLI for Fedora Server 32 so it would be easy for me to manage and have a plan that I won't have to pay for through Azure.

Things I have attempted: 
Looked through the Visual Studio Online documentation to find support for Fedora (but only found Ubuntu, CentOS, and others.)
Contacted the Visual Studio Twitter account (they recommended I should post here.)

So my overall goal would be, to run Visual Studio Online on Fedora Server 32 for access to it on [Visual Studio Online](https://online.visualstudio.com/environments)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/online/how-to/self-hosting-vscode

Comment: I have looked over that documentation before but that is for Graphical Interface versions of VSCode. I have done that method before on my personal computer but now I am planning on hosting from the CLI from an actual server but the documentation doesn't state anywhere on how to do it with the Fedora **Server** distro.

Comment: Then probably have to wait, as it is only in limited preview today. The production release should support all major Linux distributions.

Comment: That's what I would imagine being the case. I asked Visual Studio on twitter about it and they wanted me to post here. Otherwise, I would've pondered my options. Thanks.

Comment: @LexLi , my apologies for how I sounded in the other messages above. I discovered the answer and I have now answered down below. Thanks for trying to assist me anyway as I'm still getting acclimated to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day to anyone looking to resolve this issue as well! If you are trying to install VSO to your Fedora server environment, the command
`curl -L https://aka.ms/install-vso-linux | sudo bash`
will get you where you need to be according to the documentation located at the [Codespaces CLI Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/online/reference/vsonline-cli#linux). Good luck and have a great day.